# I tried to display the value of radio buttons using class name

Tags: javascript, html

I'm still new in coding. I hope I can get a kind response from you. 
Please bear with me :)  thanks
Anws,
I tried to display the value of these radio buttons but still it won't display.
May I know on how can I get the value of **.custom-control-input** when I choose a radio button using javascript?
May I know where I did it wrong?


PS: I didn't add the css here yet, what just I need is to display the value of these radio buttons.

```js
function otcContinue_onClick() {
  var tac = document.getElementsByClassName('custom-control-input');
  if (tac.checked) {
    if ($("input[name=exampleRadios]:checked").val()) {
      document.getElementById($("input[name=exampleRadios]:checked").val()).style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById('pmethods').style.display = "none";
    } else {
      $('#errorMsg').text("Please select preferred payment option.");
      $('#modalError').modal('show');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="pmethods">
  <!-- otc tab -->
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header bg-blueberry" id="headingOne">
      <h6 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed text-apple-core-light" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">Over-the-Counter Payments
        </a>
      </h6>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        <span class="small">Pay in cash at the nearest payment nearest center.</span>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 mt-2">
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
              <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="otc_sm" />
              <label class="custom-control-label text-md-left" for="exampleRadios1">
                <span class="pm-icon-holder">
                  <img src="images/otc-icons/sm.png" alt="SM" />
                </span>
                &nbsp;
                <span class="text-prussian-blue font-weight-bold small">SM Bills Pay</span>
              </label>
              <br />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-2">
          <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-8">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-apricot btn-block" onclick="otcContinue_onClick()">Continue</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end otc tab -->
</div>
<div class="mt-3">
  <!-- sm form -->
  <div id="otc_sm" class="card border-secondary mb-3 bg-payment" style="display: none">
    <div class="card-body text-prussian-blue">
      <div class="selected-logo mb-2">
        <img src="images/logos/logo_sm.png" alt="Payment Logo" />
      </div>
      <span class="card-text small">Pay in cash at the following stores. See complete list <a href="https://ptiapps.paynamics.net/OtcService/sm-guide/index.html" target="_blank" class="text-apricot font-weight-bold">here</a>.</span>
      <br />
      <br />
      <span class="card-text small">Please write down the SM Bills Payment Reference Number that will be generated once transaction has been initiated. An email will be sent to you with the transaction details.</span>
      <br />
      <div class="row mt-4">
        <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-8 mb-1">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-apricot btn-block">Continue</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-8 mb-1 text-center">
          <a href="#" class="text-blueberry font-weight-bold small"><u>Go Back</u></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end sm form -->
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Try `document.getElementsByClassName('custom-control-input')[0];` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change your JS so when you click on an input you get the returned value it has. In this case - `otc_sm`.

```js
$("input[name=exampleRadios]").on('click', function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
  document.getElementById($("input[name=exampleRadios]:checked").val()).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('pmethods').style.display = "none";
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pmethods">
  <!-- otc tab -->
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header bg-blueberry" id="headingOne">
      <h6 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed text-apple-core-light" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">Over-the-Counter Payments
        </a>
      </h6>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        <span class="small">Pay in cash at the nearest payment nearest center.</span>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 mt-2">
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
              <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="otc_sm" />
              <label class="custom-control-label text-md-left" for="exampleRadios1">
                <span class="pm-icon-holder">
                  <img src="images/otc-icons/sm.png" alt="SM" />
                </span>
                &nbsp;
                <span class="text-prussian-blue font-weight-bold small">SM Bills Pay</span>
              </label>
              <br />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-2">
          <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-8">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-apricot btn-block" onclick="otcContinue_onClick()">Continue</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end otc tab -->
</div>
<div class="mt-3">
  <!-- sm form -->
  <div id="otc_sm" class="card border-secondary mb-3 bg-payment" style="display: none">
    <div class="card-body text-prussian-blue">
      <div class="selected-logo mb-2">
        <img src="images/logos/logo_sm.png" alt="Payment Logo" />
      </div>
      <span class="card-text small">Pay in cash at the following stores. See complete list <a href="https://ptiapps.paynamics.net/OtcService/sm-guide/index.html" target="_blank" class="text-apricot font-weight-bold">here</a>.</span>
      <br />
      <br />
      <span class="card-text small">Please write down the SM Bills Payment Reference Number that will be generated once transaction has been initiated. An email will be sent to you with the transaction details.</span>
      <br />
      <div class="row mt-4">
        <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-8 mb-1">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-apricot btn-block">Continue</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-8 mb-1 text-center">
          <a href="#" class="text-blueberry font-weight-bold small"><u>Go Back</u></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end sm form -->
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: oh it works. though its not the exact code that I looked for but I got an idea. thanks for your tips